# what does it mean that theories are not true but assumed to be true?

Tags: soft-question, definition, epistemology

I have read it in most of the article and heard in videos created to explain scientific method but i am not being able to understand it .please explain to me what does it mean? give some examples.

Comment: "Truth" is a philosophical ideal. We have no idea if our human-created representations of the physical universe as embodied in physcial theories are "truth" or not.

Comment: Theories are not necessarily what happens in real world it is more of what helps us to understand why ' xyz' happens which may or may not be true but satisfies us and our mind in an attempt to understand the world

Comment: @Utkarshfutous any example!

Comment: Tell me @Remy why does gravity work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scientific theories are never actually proven, they merely reach a point they become what philosophers call "empirically sufficient."

So we have a theory of gravity.  What goes up must come down.  For now, we'll ignore the subtleties of satellites and orbits and focus on something closer to home.  You throw an apple up, it comes down.  You pick up a second apple and throw it up, and it comes down.  You pick up a third apple and throw it up.  What happens?

If you said "it comes down," then you made an assumption about how the world works based on the first two apples.  You assumed that all apples followed the same "laws of nature" and all laws of nature never change.  Thus, by those assumptions, the third apple will fall.  But you can't actually ever be certain of that, because it falling is in the future.  For all you know, *this* object exhibits anti gravity and will stay in space once you throw it.

In practice, after we see enough objects fall to the ground, we get pretty darn confident that all objects fall to the ground.  We reach the point of a "empirically sufficient" theory, where it is no longer worth your time to consider the possibility that it is wrong because there's just too much evidence to support it.

In the stock market, there's a phrase: past performance does not predict future results.  That phrase is there for a good reason.  This sort of scientific thinking has a long track record of not being effective in the stock market.  So we know there are parts of our world that are poor fits for "empirically sufficient" theories.  We also know there are parts, such as gravity, that appear to be very good fits for theories that are "empirically sufficient."  I trust my life to them on a regular basis.  But at the deepest philosophical level, they are not actually proven.  They are merely assumed, with a preponderance of evidence.

EDIT:
Remy asked in the comments:

> In your example, if apple falls every time it is a theory but why is it not truth?"

And that was a great enough question that I had to break the maximum length of comments 3 times just to fit it all in.  So I'm hauling it up into the answer where it can be read in whole:

I think the other two comments capture the answer well, but I wanted to have some fun and phrase it my way. If you said "Every apple falls every time," I'd say "really? Even the ones in the future that haven't been thrown up in the air yet," and you'd say "yes, even the future ones." And then I'd call you a quack because you have no evidence that the future apples will have had fallen. You've never seen a future apple fall. You never will. You'll only see past apples fall, and if you're really lucky, you'll see one presently fall, in the moment.

Instead you must assume that because all past apples fell, its probably true that all future apples will fall as well. But you had to make an assumption to do that. You could never be truly certain that it was true.

And, of course, one day, we did indeed throw an apple that didn't fall down. Well, technically it was a small metal sphere with 4 antennae that went blip-blip as it orbited around the earth. On that day we proved once and for all that $F=mg$ is not an all encompassing theory for apples -- not all that goes up must come down. We replaced it with Netwon's universal law of gravitation: $F=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$. And it predicts that some apples can fall into orbit instead. But how do we know all future apples will do so? For all we know, the next great scientific leap will show that theory to be false too, and the theory after that. And after that.

For we may never run short of theories, but we can never be quite sure that our current theory is the true one -- the one that is going to last. We may simply not have found it yet. Or its possible that "the last theory" may not possibly be. It's all in the future.  And that's the exciting part.  That's what keeps scientists peering around the corner and through their microscopes and wondering what they can find next.

Comment: in your example if apple falls every time it is a theory but why is it not truth?

Comment: @Remy We only know that every apple we have dropped has fallen.  We can then come up with the "theory" of gravity.  We still can't prove the next apple we drop will fall (we haven't dropped it yet!), but we can _theorize_ that it will based on our past observations (which we developed into a _theory_).

Comment: @Remy: because if you throw it hard enough, it does not come down. We have a more sophisticated theory of gravity (Newtonian gravitation) that can deal with satellites and orbits etc. Is it "true"? It's good enough to get a spacecraft to Pluto with remarkable accuracy, but it does not explain the precession of the perihelion of Mercury: you need a more sophisticated theory for that.

Comment: @Remy That's a great enough question that I added an edit to address it.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @CortAmmon thanks for more detailed answer.but i have not collected enough empirical evidence to say that my "hypothesis of understanding" has reached to "theory of understanding"  :)

Comment: @Remy Then you're on the right path!   In all seriousness, if you find this is an interesting issue for you to explore, I highly recommend taking a detour into philosophy.  The question you are digging at is one that is at the heart of the philosophy of science.  It's a great question, but it's one that can be easier to make sense of using the language of philosophy instead of just the language of science.  Plato's Allegory of the Cave is still incredibly relevant to how we make sense of the world, 2500 years later.

Comment: @CortAmmon I think eventually i have got the answer.I appreciate it,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The scientific truth for all sciences melts down to the concept that the object of science and the real object are not one and the same. As Spinoza wrote, the concept of dog does not bark.

That means that, at least, what guarantees the consistency of physics is not measurements or experiments because there is not any direct physical relation with the object of knowledge.

What makes a theory "true" in physics is mathematics. Mathematics guarantee the truth of physics.